# Stable release of Hyperledger Besu won't compile

Tags: java, besu, hyperledger

I cloned a fresh copy of Hyperledger Besu from the GitHub repo and when I opened it in Eclipse, it said that there are 148 errors and that the project won't compile.

It also said that there are 108 warnings. I'm not an expert in Java, but I can find my way around, and I assume that the Hyperledger project wouldn't put out a build labeled as stable if it wouldn't compile. A lot of the errors are related to missing classes or cyclical references.

I'm assuming I'm missing some information, but I'm not sure what it is, so I thought I'd ask here. How would I fix missing class errors, if the classes aren't in the stable build? I'm not sure where I should start looking, as I figured that all the necessary classes would be included in the project repo. Could it be the Java version?

[image: Java errors]

Comment: Besu project is based on Gradle dependency manager. If you load the project from a Gradle config it should build and solve all the issues itself. Check https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html#import-an-existing-gradle-project

Comment: Also if you have any issue, do not hesitate to ask on Besu Discord. You may have a faster answer.